# Applications for handling appointment wishes

Tags: web

This is not a "What is best" but a "Is there any at all (and which)?" question.

A friend of mine wants to improve the handling of her customers' appointment wishes. The idea is that they can enter their suitable time spans on a web site and the application checks whether all of them (or: how many) can be combined.

I am not familiar with this kind of optimization algorithm thus it would be much easier to use an existing tool than write one myself... Thus (if there is no such application) hints to resources about appropriate algorithms would be helpful.

Comment: Don't know about an existing tool (there should be a few, I'd think). Algorithm-wise though, I think you should look into the [Set Cover Problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Set_cover_problem) It's not exactly what you're trying to do, but it's close and you may find some helpful ideas there.

Comment: Check this one here. http://mrbs.sourceforge.net/ 
Though it says meeting room, it can be tweaked to suit other requirements as well.

Comment: @Ramesh Is that more than "first come, first served"?

Comment: In our school, we use it for department room booking system. So I believe if the customers enter their time the system will be smart enough to check if there is a conflict. I am not sure of if that is more than "first come, first served". But nevertheless, your friend can use some open source tools available :)

Comment: Does it have to run on a unix system? If not, you might have better luck on [softwarerecs.se] (after adapting your question to fit [the guidelines there](http://meta.softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/336/what-is-required-for-a-question-to-contain-enough-information)).